# File upload within a session

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've created a webapp that converts videos that you upload into a compilation. Locally it works perfectly because the files are simply uploaded to a folder in my project folder and the script then simply takes all the files it can find in that folder and convert it into one compilation.

However, if want to put this online and have multiple users use this webapp, I can no longer use this one folder obviously. That's where I am stuck, I don't know how I can make sure different people can upload their files simultaneously, and the script knows what files to take, and at the end delete them, once users are done with the site.

I thought maybe something with sessions or with temporary generated folders, but that is a guess. The entire website is just one page. I don't want to require users to login to use the app.

I'm very stuck and hope someone can at least point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: _"I don't want to require users to login to use the app."_ - well then you will need a session at least, to tell different clients apart. But storing huge amounts of data / file contents, into a session, is not a good idea. So, combine both - store the name of the temporary folder you create for a client, into that client's session.

Comment: _"and at the end delete them, once users are done with the site."_ - how do you know when they are "done"? If you have no explicit way of determining that, then you will have to set up some "garbage collection" task, that removes old temp folders regularly.

Comment: You can create a unique temp folder and store its path as a session variable. You could setup some javascript to send a message to the server when a user closes the page and delete the temp folder then.